Gaussian process binary classification: why are all latent function samples crossing 0 at the same location?
I am using a Gaussian process binary classifier on a multi-dimensional dataset with binary labels. The probability generally increases or decreases monotonically along each feature/dimension. For the sake of simplicity and my own understanding, I have reproduced a toy one-dimensional example problem.
In the toy dataset, probabilities should monotonically increase along the (only) dimension. The overall kernel is the sum of a RBF and a linear kernel. Below I provide a python script (using the GPy library) and the corresponding output. In addition to showing the probability prediction curve, I show samples of the latent function transformed by the (Probit) link function.
Questions: why are the probability curve and all the samples intercepting the 0.5 probability level at roughly the same location? (This means that the corresponding latent function curves all intersect f=0 at the same location - why is that?) Is it possible to modify the kernel and obtain function samples that do not cross at the same location?
I'm asking this question because the "true" 0.5 probability intercept (which could be estimated with a very large and dense dataset) might in reality be at a different location. I would like to be able to generate probability curve samples that reflect this.
The script:
import numpy as np
import GPy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# Toy 1D dataset
X = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]).reshape((-1,1))
t = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]).reshape((-1,1))

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)

X_test = np.linspace(0, 35, 50).reshape(-1, 1)

# GPy model
rbf = GPy.kern.RBF(input_dim=1, variance=1., lengthscale=1.)
lin = GPy.kern.Linear(input_dim=1, variances=1.)

m = GPy.core.GP(
    X=X_scaled,
    Y=t, 
    kernel=rbf + lin, 
    inference_method=GPy.inference.latent_function_inference.laplace.Laplace(),
    likelihood=GPy.likelihoods.Bernoulli())
m.optimize_restarts(num_restarts=10, optimizer='lbfgs', robust=True)

# Predicted probability curve
pred = m.predict(scaler.transform(X_test))[0]

# Sample curves (sample latent function, transform with link function (Probit))
latent_f_samples = m.posterior_samples_f(scaler.transform(X_test), size=10)
proba_samples = m.likelihood.gp_link.transf(latent_f_samples)[:,0,:]

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.scatter(X[t==1], t[t==1], label="Class 1", s=100, marker="x", color="red")
ax.scatter(X[t==0], t[t==0], label="Class 0", s=100, marker="+", color="blue")

ax.plot(X_test, pred, color='k', label='Predicted', zorder=5)
ax.plot(X_test, proba_samples, alpha=0.3, color='gray', zorder=0)
ax.axhline(0.5, X_test.min(), X_test.max(), color='black', ls='--', lw=0.5)

ax.set_title(f"Predicted probabilities and sampled probability curves")
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('p(class 1)')
ax.set_xlim(X_test.min(), X_test.max())
ax.legend()

The output:

What I would like the samples to look like (if ever possible):

